# Can you enable watchdog in iOS for debug mode?

Tags: ios, debugging, watchdog

One of my apps got rejected because it exceeded the startup time limit. The watchdog process killed it. **Is there any way you can enable this watchdog component in debug mode?** I've read somewhere that it's disabled for debugging purposes (which seems logical to me). Just wondering if you can manually enable it with some setting or something.

Btw, I know how to fix this problem, moving the whole startup code to a background thread did the trick.

Anyone got an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well it's active when you launch an app not through Xcode (i.e. with no debugger attached), so you could just install your app via Xcode, unplug it, launch the app. Then you'll see if it takes too long. But really, you shouldn't be thinking that you need that as a feature during debugging. You should just return ASAP from `applicationDidFinishLaunching` and do your work later like you have mentioned.

Comment: @maxmitz what doesn’t work since iOS 14? The steps here are just basically “launch app not in a debugger”. Watchdog will be active in that case.